# clicar em span e marcar checkbox

Tags: html, html5

Estou tentando fazer com que ao clicar encima do span, o checkbox seja marcado, mas parece estar com algum erro.

Me ajudem por favor.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="remember_pass"> <span for="remember_pass"> Lembrar senha</span>
```

Eu já tinha feito isso uma vez, porém desta vez não está funcionando.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro é que vc usou um `span` e deveria ser uma `label` o atributo `for=""` só funciona na `<label>`

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="remember_pass"> <label for="remember_pass"> Lembrar senha</label>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, erro simples...

Comment: @SamuelMachado são tantas tags que as vezes a gente se confunde mesmo rss. Se quiser mais informação sobre a Label aqui tem um link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes

Comment: Obrigado, confunde mesmo kkk

Comment: @SamuelMachado sem problemas 

Comment: @SamuelMachado depois lembre-se de marcar a resposta como assista nesse ícone ✔ ao lado das setinhas da resposta caso vc ache que tenha resolvido o problema. Assim a pergunta não fica em aberto pendente no site respondida , mas não aceita